# ggplot2 - 4 categorical and 1 continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to create a graph like the one below in R but it has proved to be harder than just doing it in excel. X is a categorical variable, y is continuous, then colour would be a dichotomous variable and line type another. How can I go about doing it? I tried using the following code but if I change one of the line dimensions or colour it just gives a notice "Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line". How can I adapt it?

```
ggplot(RT, aes(x= Block, y= mean, group = Probability, color=Probability))+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-CI, ymax=mean+CI), width=.1, 
            position=position_dodge(0.05)) + xlab("Epoch") +
 geom_line(aes(linetype=Probability), size = 1) + 
 geom_point(aes(shape=Probability))+
facet_wrap(~ Session, scales="free") + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(370, 530)) + 
  scale_color_grey(start=0.85, end=0.2)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image: 5]

[image]

Comment: Can you add , please, a reproducible example?

Comment: @iago Would you need some data? Or is it enough to give some gist of it? The variables would be: x (between  and ); y (continuous variable - representing Response times); variable 1 (between 1 and 2) and variable 2 (between 1 and 2). I mention that there are five variables, but the fifth would result in two graphs, one for each session. I am having trouble with representing the two variables (variable 1 and 2) in the same graph.

Comment: Yes, some reproducible data is necessary (look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As in the answer of @allan-cameron: does it not answer your question? why? which is different in your data with the example data.frame he defines? It is because of this you has to add reproducible data, to know exactly what you want.

Comment: Hope the dataset helps, I just did not manage to figure out what they meant by "group" as I only have four variables per graph, with the fifth being for the facet_wrap. So to me only the "ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, y, color = var1, linetype = var2), stat="identity")" + facet_wrap(~ var3, scales="free") makes sense. But it does not result in the graph I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to make an interaction variable from your vars `var1` and `var2` which gives a factor with four levels representing the four `series`. (Basically this corresponds to the `group` variable in the answer by @AllanCameron). This new interaction variable can then be mapped on both `color` and `linetype` which results in one legend. The colors and linetypes can then be set via `scale_color_manual` and `scale_linetype_manual`. try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = factor(rep(1:2, each = 20, length = 40)),
  x = rep(1:5, each = 4),
  var2 = factor(rep(1:2, each = 2)),
  var3 = factor(rep(1:2, each = 1)),
  y = runif(40, 300, 500)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(series = interaction(var1, var2, sep = "_")) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x, y, color = series, linetype = series), stat="identity") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "orange", "black", "black"),
                     labels = paste0("series", 1:4)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "solid", "dashed", "solid"),
                        labels = paste0("series", 1:4)) +
  facet_wrap(~ var3, scales="free") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: I wish I could have selected both yours and Ben's responses as I used a combination of both. But since I would not manage to get there without your interaction argument I decided to accept yours as the correct one. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do by adding a grouping variable and group aesthetic. Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)

vals <- c(11, 13, 12, 14)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:4, 4),
  y = c(vals, 2 * vals, 3 * vals, 4 * vals),
  colours = rep(c("#bf6424", "black"), each = 8),
  linetype = rep(rep(2:1, each = 4), 2),
  group = rep(1:4, each = 4))


ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = colours, linetype = linetype, group = group)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_linetype_identity() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to see what is going wrong if you post a sample of your data so that we could take your ggplot code and run it to see what happens.

However, a quick inspection of your code reveals some issues. You are mapping your `Probability` variable to four aesthetics: group, color, linetype, and shape. Each of group, color, and linetype needs to be mapped to a different variable.

Here is a minimal example. In this example, I have a dummy variable called `group` that separates each line. I map `var1` to color and `var2` to linetype. Since my data only has one point per combination of x, y, group, color, and linetype, I need to set `stat = identity` to let `geom_line` know this is intentional.

```
df <- data.frame(x = factor(rep(1:4, 4)),
                 y = c(10, 15, 10, 15, 20, 25, 20, 25, 30, 35, 30, 35, 40, 45, 40, 45),
                 group = factor(c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4))),
                 var1 = factor(c(rep(0, 8), rep(1, 8))),
                 var2 = factor(c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4)))
                 )
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x, y, group = group, color = var1, linetype = var2), stat="identity")
```

Here is the plot it produces.

[image: a line plot with four lines of different color and linetype]

Comment: I think I was not entirely clear, I am sorry. I have four categorical variables, one is the x, another is what you represented as var1 and var2 and finally there is a fourth one that is supposed to result into two separate graphs (hence the facet_wrap(~ Session, scales="free")). I have been trying to use your example but I am not sure what you are representing by the variable "group".